# How to assign value to the datagridviewtextboxcolumn in code behind?

Tags: c#, gridview, desktop-application, assign, datagridviewtextboxcell

I have a gridview of type datagridviewtextbox column.

It has following fields.

```
SrNo.    | Description    | HSN Code    | Qty   | Rate   | Amount
```

I have fetched records of "Description", "HSN Code" , "Qty" & "Rate" in the dataset.

I Want to generate the "SrNo" and "Amount" in my program.

My code is:

```
int i=0;
ds = new DataSet();
ds = db.getDetailRecords(Convert.ToInt32(txtBillNo.Text));


for (i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
     grdData.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = i;
     grdData.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Description"].ToString();
     grdData.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["HSNCode"].ToString();
     grdData.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Qty"].ToString();
     grdData.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Rate"].ToString();
     grdData.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = Convert.ToDouble(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Qty"]) * Convert.ToDouble(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Rate"]);                        
}
```

But it's not working. It gives the error that `Index was out of Range.`

How do I assign the dataset values to the grid?
Please help.

Comment: Well have you defined the columns in the `datagridview` ? then you will have to add a row to it coz the grid won't have any rows (i assume you are not binding anything to the grid) like `grdData.Rows.Add()`

Comment: Yes the grid columns are previously defined.
I don't know how to work with adding new row?
Will you please provide some code? @V4Vendetta

Comment: Please show more code, the code how you intialized the grid view??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you skipped the `DataBinding` to `GridView`:

```
int i=0;
ds = new DataSet();
ds = db.getDetailRecords(Convert.ToInt32(txtBillNo.Text));
grdData.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; // you skipped this
```

Comment: Thanks Sir, data is displayed properly..
But one problem is arose that the columns are displayed twice. @Praveen Nambiar

Comment: The grid's predefined columns as well as the columns from the dataset are also displayed.

Comment: Set `AutoGenerateColumns="false"`

Comment: As always it works perfectly...

Thank you so much Sir. @Praveen Nambiar

Comment: Sir I need some more help. Please see my this [Question][http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918309/set-focus-to-data-grid-view-text-box-column-cell] @Praveen Nambiar

Answer (score 1):

Is the dataset table created with these two columns "SrNo" and "Amount"?

If not, that's the reason you're getting that exception. I know you want to generate them on the fly but to access the fields like that they must at least be present in the dataset's table, namely `ds.Tables[0]`.

Be sure `db.getDetailRecords` returns a valid `DataSet` for the columns you're asking for.

Oh, plus the datagridview doesn't have any rows. I suggest you bind it to your dataset before changing anything, you can do that by setting the DataGridView's `DataSource` property.

```
int i=0;
ds = new DataSet();
ds = db.getDetailRecords(Convert.ToInt32(txtBillNo.Text));

//add this
grdData.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

for (i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
     grdData.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = i;
     //You don't need to set the other properties, they were binded when you put the DataSource in there
     grdData.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = Convert.ToDouble(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Qty"]) * Convert.ToDouble(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Rate"]);                        
}
```

Be sure that `SrNo` and `Amount` are respectively the columns 0 and 5 in your DataSource.

Comment: Yes sir,I have checked the dataset and the records are successfully returned. But I don't know how to work with the grid view row.. @Conrad CLark

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code:

```
int i=0;
ds = new DataSet();
ds = db.getDetailRecords(Convert.ToInt32(txtBillNo.Text));

grdData.Rows.Clear()
for (i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
     grdData.Rows.Add(); /// For add a Row. then does not show index out of range error
     grdData.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = i;
     grdData.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Description"].ToString();
     grdData.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["HSNCode"].ToString();
     grdData.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Qty"].ToString();
     grdData.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Rate"].ToString();
     grdData.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = Convert.ToDouble(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Qty"]) * Convert.ToDouble(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Rate"]);                        
}
```

Comment: I don't know how cells are created when you add a new row this way. Maybe it will give you another `Index was out of Range.` because of the cells?

Comment: @ConradClark How can you tell like this.? This wont give OP any error.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)

use for that (i = 0; i == ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
//  not show index out of range
```

Because dgv as datagridview index starts from 0 and ds as dataset also from 0.

Autogenerated column should be false;