# Not able to bind the grid view in code behind desktop application

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview, desktop-application

I have a grid view which lists all the customers.

I am binding it in the load time of Form which is placed in the child of MDI.

Columns in the grid view is predefined at the design time.

My code for the `Form_Load()` event is:

```
try
{
       cn = db.createConnection();
       if (cn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
       {
           cn.Close();
       }
       cn.Open();
       cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select BillNo,PartyName,City,State,FORMAT(BillDt,'dd-mm-yyyy') as BillDt from BillMaster", cn);
       da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
       ds = new DataSet();
       da.Fill(ds);
       cn.Close();

       dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
       dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
       for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
       {
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["BillNo"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["PartyName"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["City"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["State"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["BillDt"].ToString();
        }

   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
   }
   finally
   {
       cn.Close();
       da.Dispose();
       ds.Dispose();
       cmd.Dispose();
   }

}
```

I checked the program execution by putting the breakpoints. The data is fetched exactly as database in the DataSet and Immediate Window the value of particular cell of grid shows the exact value but the problem is when the form is loaded the grid remains empty. And creates the number of blank rows same as the number of rows fetched from the database.

What should I do to tackle this error.

Please help.

Comment: Could you show us your Designer.cs file?

Comment: Did you mean Designing form na?

Comment: [this](http://i.imgur.com/h6N95nG.png) is my form. But grid remains empty. It is expected to be filled with the data displayed in it.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```

to `true`. Remove

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
   {
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["BillNo"].ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["PartyName"].ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["City"].ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["State"].ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["BillDt"].ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Not sure I would set AutoGenerateColumns to false unless they are predefined

Comment: Yes, the columns are predefined in the design time.

Comment: That's because it wasn't there :)

Answer (score 0):

first thing and maybe I am missing something but:

this is redundant, I would remove it, it could be part of the problem

```
 for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
   {
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["BillNo"].ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["PartyName"].ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["City"].ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["State"].ToString();
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["BillDt"].ToString();
    }
```

this should already take care of that

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: Sir, should I remove the `for` loop or remove the `dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];` statement? @Micah Armantrout

Comment: what happens if you set autogen columns to true just for the fun of it

Comment: When I set auto generate columns to true it gives blank grid view as an output.

Comment: no MDI shouldn't matter ... so it does the same no matter if AutoGen is set to true or false ?

Comment: yeah, it gives no effect on output.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28275/discussion-between-micah-armantrout-and-riyaz-kalva)

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
   cn = db.createConnection();
   if (cn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
   {
       cn.Close();
   }
   cn.Open();
   cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select BillNo,PartyName,City,State,FORMAT(BillDt,'dd-mm-yyyy') as BillDt from BillMaster", cn);
   da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
   ds = new DataSet();
   da.Fill(ds);
   cn.Close();

   dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
   dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

   //Or you can use
   //dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;    


   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
   }
   finally
   {
   cn.Close();
   da.Dispose();
   ds.Dispose();
   cmd.Dispose();
  }

  }
```

Hope it helps you