# String was no recognized as a valid Date TIme Error in Desktop Application

Tags: c#, cross-platform, desktop-application, datetimepicker

I have developed an application which is compatible with .net Framework 3.5 to run the build of it in other applications also.

The O. S. of built application is Windows 7.

And when I run the build in Windows XP [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVYm2.png) error occurs for following code:

```
dtBillDate.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Dt"].ToString();
```

Here `dtBillDate` is a DateTimePickerControl.

And the SQL query to fill `ds` records is:

```
query = "Select M.BillNo,M.PartyName,M.Address,M.City,M.State,M.TaxType,
M.BillType,FORMAT(M.BillDt,'dd-mm-yyyy')as Dt,
M.CST,M.GST,M.TransportName,M.TruckNo,M.Through,M.Tax,M.AddTax,M.Charges from BillMaster M where M.BillNo=" + billNo;
```

Records are stored in the Access 2007 database.

What changes I should make to tackle the error.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are formatting your Date in your query

```
FORMAT(M.BillDt,'dd-mm-yyyy')as Dt
```

*In your format `mm` should `MM`, since you probably need month, not minutes*

You should use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) with the format `dd-MM-yyyy` to parse the date. Although its better if you let your query return the DateTime without formatting, and let .Net application format your date for displaying.

You need to set `DateTimePicker` control value to show the date. You can use `DateTime.ParseExact` to parse like:

```
dtBillDate.Value = DateTime.ParseExact(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Dt"].ToString(), 
                                       "dd-MM-yyyy", 
                                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer sir, i tried your suggested code but still it gives the same error . @Habib

Comment: Sorry, it does not give error at compile time. And the error is [this](http://i.imgur.com/8ibzcLQ.png) @Habib

Comment: @RiyazKalva, did you change the query to with format as `MM` (upper case `MM`)

Comment: Yes Sir, it is the same...

My code line is:

`dtBillDate.Value = DateTime.ParseExact(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["BillDt"].ToString(),"dd-MM-yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: @RiyazKalva, put a break point and see what you get in `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["BillDt"].ToString()`

Comment: Sir, I checked the record value and getting `09-04-2013 12:00:00 AM`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28955/discussion-between-riyaz-kalva-and-habib)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28967/discussion-between-riyaz-kalva-and-habib)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateTime dateTime;
string dateString = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Dt"].ToString();
bool result = DateTime.TryParse(dateString , out dateTime);

if(result)
{
     // Use `dateTime` variable then
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically in win 7 the "English INDIA " format is available, in which the date separator is "-". But in Win XP " English India" Format is not available, so u might be using " English US or UK" format for date which use "/" as a date separator.

TO Solve your problem ,all you gotta do is change the date separator format to "-" in your win xp machine by going to  > CONTROL PANEL>REGION AND LANGUAGE OPTIONS> Click On "Customize" > OPEN The "DATE" Tab and here set the DATE SEPARATOR to "-".
And Your Application Will Work Without any error. Happy Now  :D