# SetFocus on Gridview from another form textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview

I need to be set focus on Gridview First row and first Cell(Type of Reference):

Below on my Actual Result and Expected result:

1. Actual Result: (Once i Leave from the DailyCAsh Form1(Txtamt.text(1500) )to set focus on Bill Reference Form2(txtBillwise.text(Airtel bill)
   [image]
2. Expected Result: Once i leave form1 Daily Cash(Textamt.text(1500)) set focus on Bill Reference form2(Grd_View First Row and second column(Type_of_Reference=Advance)
   [image]

How Could I do this? i am new to .net

Comment: Have you looked here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918309/set-focus-to-data-grid-view-text-box-column-cell

Comment: Have you tried what has been suggested by @DeJaVo ?

Comment: I was tried , but it 's not working and moreover i have 2 different form , have to set focus one form text box(amount) to another form grid view first row second cell(Type of Ref). @DeJaVo,@P.K.